# Using Web Browser as a Thin Client to Access certain applications on Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, when a user clicks on the submit button of that application, the server should capture all the information in the form, and call a local windows application ( located at "c:\Program Files..." and do some processing before passing back the data to the users.

Now, is this possible? Is there any security restriction on web application calling local application?

In other words, can I start a new process inside my asp.net application by using the [System.Diagnostic.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Now, is this possible?* 
Yes

*Is there any security restriction on web application calling local application?*
You should check on what role your IIS is working for such operations, for example if your IIS is working under NETWORK SERVICE role and don't have access right to process path you want to execute, then it will fail...

*can I start a new process inside my asp.net application by using the System.Diagnostic.Process class?*
I haven't tried so far but I don't think there will be restriction about this, you can think asp.net application just like any other windows app most of the times.